# Roles in play framework (java): is it built-in?

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.2, user-roles

I'm currently developing an application with play framework 2.2.6 in java. My system needs to make difference between two user-roles: admins and users.

So far, I know using the Security.Authenticator class to prevent not logged-in access functionality within my system.

But once inside, I need to separate functionality of both Admins and Users: I wanna prevent Users making use of Admins use cases (for instance).

Is there any way built-in within Play framework to do so (perhaps something additional to work with Authenticator)?

Thanks mates!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found any interesting built-in authorization module. Play docs tell us to take a look at Deadbolt, so I'd say you must check

http://deadbolt.ws/#/java-docs

and

https://github.com/schaloner/deadbolt-2

Once that's the one they tell us to do.
I tried Deadbolt2 and looks pretty nice.
Hope it helps